# NetBeans won't print to console JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans

I have written a simple program in the NetBeans IDE using Java. After making a few changes to the main method this morning, the console does not print anything when I run the program. I simply want it to reach startMenus(sc). EDIT: I have now put in a few System.out.println() and it does not reach "Blah2" which is right after my first loop...

```
public class Calculator {

public static int[] NUMBERS;    //global value for the array

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {      
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    System.out.println("Blah1");

    int counter = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        counter = counter++;
    }

    System.out.println("Blah2");

    int lenth = counter;

    NUMBERS = new int[lenth];

    System.out.println("Blah3");

    sc.close();

    File file2 = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(file2);

    System.out.println("Blah4");

    int i = 0;

    while (sc2.hasNextInt()) {
        NUMBERS[i] = sc2.nextInt();
        ++i;
    }

    System.out.println("Blah5");

    sc2.close();


    System.out.println("Welcome to Calculation Program!\n");
    startMenus(sc);

}
}
```

Comment: Any exceptions? The main method is noted to throw an exception, but who or what is handling that exception?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't because it just didn't finish the loop before you thought it didn't do it?

Comment: Try a System.out at the program start, to be sure :)

Comment: I have an output window.

Comment: I tried  System.out.println("Blah blah blah"); and it printed when I ran it

Comment: I believe @11684 was onto something with the loop...

Comment: @lancer I made it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't throwing any other exceptions that are killing your app before it reaches System.out.println? Judging by your description you may want to either debug or put some other println statements further up the chain as it could be dying due to something.

Comment: I'm only throwing the FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {    

    public static int[] NUMBERS;    //global value for the array

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    file.createNewFile();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    int counter = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        counter = counter++;
    }

    int lenth = counter;

    NUMBERS = new int[lenth];

    sc.close();

    File file2 = new File("data.txt");
    file2.createNewFile();
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(file2);

    int i = 0;

    while (sc2.hasNextInt()) {
        NUMBERS[i] = sc2.nextInt();
        ++i;
    }

    sc2.close();


    System.out.println("Welcome to Calculation Program!\n");
    startMenus(sc);

}

    private static void startMenus(Scanner sc) {
        System.out.println("Run your code here!!!");
    }
}
```

Couple of things:

1. You need to import additional classes that are not part of your core project. Exceptions, File, and Scanner all fall into this category.
2. You need to run the createNewFile() method to actually create your file. Your original code was throwing a FileNotFound exception because the file was never being created.
3. You need to have the startMenus method defined before calling it.

I've included some corrected code. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have the startMenus method in the program, I just did not post it here. I also have created the files and put them into the same folder as the project. Let me try the IOException and see if that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

The System.out calls probably wheren't reached yet, because one of your loops took too long to execute, longer then you were willing to wait. Log something from inside a loop to get some more feedback, the program is probably fine.

Comment: I believe the first loop is infinite. So I need to somehow consume each integer as it reads from the file...

Comment: Your first loop indeed doesn't consume the integer, so the scanner will always have a next int (except when it has none at all) because you never move on. Fix it by adding `sc.nextInt();` to the loop body (without catching that int (if you don't need it)).